# Get Data from Perl format and update sql table

Tags: mysql, json, perl, url

I'm relatively new to Perl and trying to self teach. However i have read all of the related threads on this page and others and none of them seem to work for me.

Below is my code - trying to get a lot of data from a webpage in Perl format and export it to update values in an SQL table.

Currently i can't even data dumper the results of the url out.

Any help would be great.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use LWP::Simple;
use warnings;
use strict;
use JSON qw( decode_json from_json );
use LWP::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use utf8;

my $url = "http://.sensitivedata.txt";

my @json= from_json(get ( $url ));
die "Couldn't get $url" if not defined @json;

##my $decoded_json = decode_json( @json);

print Dumper @json;

exit 0;
```

This is the error message it is giving me: 
    defined(@array) is deprecated at alarms.pl line 14.
    (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
    malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at     character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at /opt/csw/share/perl/csw/JSON.pm line 168

Comment: "malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom" means the `get` is not returning valid JSON. Print the results of the `get` before trying to parse it as JSON to verify what it looks like: `my $content = get $url; print $content;` Edit the results into your post.

Comment: I'll have a try now thanks. The url is a .txt url will this affect the JSON data?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear about a) what the problem is and b) how to get rid of it.

> defined(@array) is deprecated at alarms.pl line 14. (Maybe you should
>   just omit the defined()?)

Calling `defined()` on `@json` is pointless. You're really just checking to see if there is any data in the array so replace `if not defined @json` with `if not @json`.

That will get rid of the error message. But you'll still have a problem as your program will almost certainly now die on the same line with the error message "Couldn't get http://.sensitivedata.txt". And that's probably not an accurate error message.

The problem is that this error can be caused by two problems. Either you can't get the data or you can't parse the data. Your error message only mentions one of these possibilities. Better to split the error checking into two.

```
# Step 1: Get the data
my $raw_json = get($url);
die "Can't get data from $url" unless $raw_json;

# Step 2: Parse the data
my @json = from_json($raw_json);
if (!@json) {
  warn $raw_json;
  die "Can't parse data from $url";
}
```

With code more like this, you'll be able to see what the problem is.

There's another little problem here, so to pre-empt your next question...

`from_json` always returns a scalar. It will either be a hash reference or an array reference (depending on the JSON you get). Looks like you're expecting an array. You'll need to store the reference in a scalar and dereference it.

```
my $json_array_ref = from_json($raw_json);
if (!@$json_array_ref) {
  warn $raw_json;
  die "Can't parse data from $url";
}
my @json = @$json_array_ref;
```